# CakePHP - Selective SSL

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, ssl

How do I force HTTPS for certain parts of a site, e.g. a login page or register page, and use HTTP for the rest of the site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selectively enabling SSL for certain actions in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751338/selectively-enabling-ssl-for-certain-actions-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite convert to https forcing method is to put this as the first thing in your php script.  It works in Joomla, and may very well work in CakePHP.

```
if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {           
header('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/'.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); 
die();
}
```

This snippet will force https on whatever page you are viewing.  If you want to isolate certian pages, just put some conditions based on the information in the "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" variable.

Otherwise, modify the .htaccess file, assuming your host allows you access to this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} somefolder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/somefolder/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the exact thing with CodeIgniter.  I'm not totally familiar with CakePHP but I'm sure the process is similar.

1. I setup apache to point SSL and non-SSL traffic to the same directory.
2. Then I created an array in the config that listed which controllers needed to have SSL (register, login, etc)
3. Then created a function in an autoloaded helper that checked to see if the current controller was in that array and then it would reset the `base_url` with `https://` instead of `http://`.  If the controller wasn't in the array, it would force the `base_url` to `http://`.

Worked flawlessly for me. Let me know if code examples from my CodeIgniter project would be helpful.

[Similar post that may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751338/selectively-enabling-ssl-for-certain-actions-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

You may load the RequestHandler component and use the isSsl() function to determine if it is coming from a http or https, if !isSsl then redirect it to a https page :) else do whatever other thing you want.

book info of the isSsl function [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1292/Obtaining-Request-Information)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be doing this with mod_rewrite with htaccess for certain Url's and leaving the code out of it all together.

You can setup your rewrite rules for just certain Url's.

Here is a lead on how to do it for an entire site:

http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/force-ssl-htaccess.html